# How to stop display of container when declaring an empty variable/object in js/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, declare

```
const readline = require('readline');

x = [];

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  rl.close();
  console.log(answer);
  x.push(answer);
});

console.log(x);
```

Output:

```
What do you think of Node.js? []
```

I would like to declare an empty array without it displaying '[]' so that it would just say:
"What do you think of Node.js?"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question at all. Would you please revise the question to be a little more clear?

Comment: If you're asking how to get it to not display `[]`, don't include `console.log(x)`, since `x` at the point your reach the line is `[]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way would just to  check the array's length and pass what you want displayed

```
//if it has any length display array as normal
//otherwise just pass empty string
console.log( x.length? x : "" );
```

Another option is you could just `join()` the array elements which will give you an empty string for empty arrays, and a comma separated list for non-empty

```
console.log(x.join())
```

A final option would be to use a custom inspect function. `console.log` in the nodejs environment ultimately calls [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), or similar native function, for objects. Because of this you can add a [custom inspect function](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects) that allows you to return a string of what you want displayed for that object.

So again you would just test the array's length return an empty string in the case of empty array or return what the `util.inspect` method would have original returned

```
Array.prototype[util.inspect.custom] = function(){
  if(!this.length){
    return "";
  }
  //passe customInspect:false so the custom inspect method wont be called again
  return util.inspect(this,{customInspect:false});
}
```

Of course this method would effect all arrays being logged or inspected so use it only if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
const readline = require('readline');

x = [];

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  rl.close();
  x.push(answer);
  console.log(x[0]);
});
```